# Request should hit particular Web Front End server

Tags: sharepoint-server

For instance, I have 3 WFE's servers. WhenIi access an url in the browser, Request should go to 1st web front end server and get response from that. How can we do that?

Comment: what is the reason for this? permanent solution or just for testing?

Comment: not for testing. I am looking for a solution....

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a load balancer that determines which WFE receives which traffic. What are you using for a load balancer? F5.. Windows Server? In what scenario do you want particular traffic going to a particular WFE? Is it IP related? You can create rules to direct load balancing traffic towards certain WFEs. If you are just trying to test a certain WFE, turn off the other two temporarily maybe at a time when traffic is low so that there is no interruption in service.

Comment: How to create rules to direct load balancing traffic towards certain WFE's?

Comment: using Lb-F5 and Windows server - 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just needing to do some tests w/ respect to a certain WFE, you can always use your HOST file to point your requests to a specific IP.  This is a quick and easy method for individual testing, but if you're needing to do more wide scale, Brian's comments regarding load balancing rules or manually restricting your available WFEs would be the go-to.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will kill the purpose of Load balancer. But you can thing about couple of options.

1. Simply by pass the LoadBalancer and Point your DNS directly to the WFE where you want. Unless you have some reason to use the LB.
2. In Loadbalancer, when you create pool on your LB at that simply add only server which you want to use.  This way Loadbalancer fwd request to server A(which is only server in pool) and if that server is down your site will be down.

Comment: Creating an app pool on Lb.How? I am not sure about this....Can u please give a clarification on that

Comment: Not app pool....On your F5( i am guessing) when you configure the LB for your URL then you create Pool in which you mentioned that ips of the server which will be part of the LB

Comment: read this https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_pools.html